# scrollMagic - How to scroll to the right place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollmagic

There is such a thing.
https://jsfiddle.net/j6u6wp7x/1/

```
var scene;
var controller;
$(document).ready(function() {
    parallaxAuto();
    $('.viewer__nav div').click(function(event) {
        var num = $(this).attr('data-num');
        if (num == 'sticky') {
            controller.scrollTo(scene);
        }
        var scrollPos = controller.info("scrollPos");
    });
});

function hideShow(num, block) {
  block.find("div.active").removeClass("active").animate({ opacity: 0,},300);
  block.find("div.slide"+num).addClass("active").animate({ opacity: 1,},300);
}
// init variables
function parallaxAuto() {
    var viewer       = document.querySelector('.viewer.active'),
    frame_count  = 5,
    offset_value = 500;

    // init controller
    controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 0,
        reverse: true
      }
    });

    // build pinned scene
    scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#sticky',
      duration: (frame_count * offset_value) + 'px',
      reverse: true
    })
    .setPin('#sticky')
    //.addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

    // build step frame scene
    for (var i = 1, l = frame_count; i <= l; i++) {
      new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: '#sticky',
          offset: i * offset_value
        })
        .setClassToggle(viewer, 'frame' + i)
        //.addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
    }
}
```

Below there are 3 smaller images that create Navigation. I made it to jump to the top, but I cannot figure out how to jump to 2nd or 3rd.

`var scrollPos = controller.info ( "scrollPos");` shows the current position, but I cannot imagine how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't go through the tit-bits of your code, but in similar situations we used the `scrollIntoView()` function of JavaScript(not jQuery).

```
var element = document.getElementById('id of your image');
element.scrollIntoView(false);
```

This much code should do the trick.
Hope it helps.

**EDIT :1**

Hi, I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxbm7shu/), I think we need to store the scenes in a array and then refer it later. I guess you were looking for something like that.

Comment: and if I have an image substituted by background-image? @SamGhatak

Comment: in such cases, you can use the `document.getElementsbByClassName('classname');` to get the element...as I can see the background image is added through css class

Comment: and if the class has not yet been added?) @SamGhatak

Comment: so how are you adding the background image without any specific ID or class??

Comment: The background image is added by adding a class. but that, if we assume a class has not yet been added, but I need to go on the navigation to the right place?

Comment: ok, what is the defination of 'right place'? I mean, the right place is basically a dom element, right? so if we know the right place, we should be able to identify the dom-element as well...

Comment: See, there is one block in this block when scrolling added classes and changing the image. I am wondering how to be, if the class has not yet been added but the user clicks on the navigation to go to the slide. You see?

Comment: @AлександрКотов : Added a fiddle reference, i think that might be helpful

Comment: Can you at the same time as a prompt to do so when scrolling navigation elements are highlighted? @SamGhatak

Comment: Sorry, didn't get u...u want the shortcut elements highlighted when the respective scene is in view?

Comment: sorry man, a bit busy...did't find time to look into it...for the time, i can suggest to create a css class for highlighting and toggle it among the links

Comment: Well, add this class I realized. I can not understand how to monitor the scene change @SamGhatak

Comment: Here, I've created a separate issue. Can you help me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906729/highlight-active-navigation-element-when-scrolling @SamGhatak